# Esper How To Join Tables

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing, nesper

I m sure that this statement works in Esper:

```
/* query from table TableA when receive event PriceEvent */
ON PriceEvent p
SELECT a.SymbolA, p.price
FROM TableA a
WHERE a.Symbol = p.Symbol
```

But this statement throws error:

```
/* join table TableA with TableB */
ON PriceEvent p
SELECT a.SymbolA, p.price, b.SymbolB
FROM TableA a, TableB b
WHERE a.Key = b.Key and a.Symbol = p.Symbol
```

Error Message:

```
com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementSyntaxException: Incorrect syntax near ',' expecting end-of-input but found a comma ','
```

Then I use JOIN but it still doesn't work:

```
/* join table TableA with TableB */
ON PriceEvent p
SELECT a.SymbolA, p.price, b.SymbolB
FROM TableA a inner join TableB b
ON a.Key = b.Key
WHERE a.Symbol = p.Symbol
```

Error Message:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'join' (a reserved keyword) expecting end-of-input but found 'join'
```

How to join two tables in Esper?

Answer (score 1):

The on-select only allows only a single named window or table and not multiple. Joins are just "select * from A, B, C...." and you can look into using "unidirectional".

Comment: i see...is there any way to join Table with Event?

Comment: yes, the doc has examples. The from clause can also have tables, named windows and external stuff like jdbc/rdbms or a method providing the join data.